# SQL generated by Laravel doesn't work, but if I run the SQL direct on PhpMyAdmin it works

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to get the name of Users in my system and I use the following code on PHP Laravel:

```
$course_assessments = CourseAssessment::where('canvas_assignment_id', '=', $canvas_assignment_id)
        ->join('assessment_submissions', 'assessment_submissions.courses_assessments_id', '=', 'course_assessments.id')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'assessment_submissions.evaluated_user')
        ->groupby('users.name')
        ->get();
```

When I run the code I got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'laravel.course_assessments.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `course_assessments` inner join `assessment_submissions` on `assessment_submissions`.`courses_assessments_id` = `course_assessments`.`id` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `assessment_submissions`.`evaluated_user` where `canvas_assignment_id` = 248302 group by `assessment_submissions`.`evaluated_user`)
```

But if I get the SQL code from the error above:

```
select * from `course_assessments` inner join `assessment_submissions` on `assessment_submissions`.`courses_assessments_id` = `course_assessments`.`id` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `assessment_submissions`.`evaluated_user` where `canvas_assignment_id` = 248302 group by `assessment_submissions`.`evaluated_user`
```

and I run the code on PhpMyAdmin, the code it works, but show me this warning message:

```
Current selection does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.
```

How can I fix that on Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you group rows with GROUP BY, the database doesn't know which row should be selected. You have to specifically tell the database which row to be shown, for example, `FIRST(name)` will select the first row of column name.

Except the column in GROUP BY, which will be unique.

So in your query, `select *` won't work, you should add `select()` and specify the field and aggregate function.

```
        ->select('users.name', DB::raw('FIRST(course_assessments.field_name)'))
```

`users.name` is in GROUP BY so it doesn't need aggregate function, other fields need aggregate function.

Comment: I try to add ->select('users.name', DB::raw('FIRST(users.name)')) in my query , but it didn't work. I really don't understand of how I need to use the select function in my query.

Comment: @fabiobh the second one is just an example since I don't know your field names, try changing inside FIRST() to your field name.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**From:**

```
 $course_assessments = CourseAssessment::where('canvas_assignment_id', '=', $canvas_assignment_id)
            ->join('assessment_submissions', 'assessment_submissions.courses_assessments_id', '=', 'course_assessments.id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'assessment_submissions.evaluated_user')
            ->groupby('users.name')
            ->get();
```

**To:**

```
 $course_assessments = CourseAssessment::where('assessment_submissions.canvas_assignment_id', '=', $canvas_assignment_id)
            ->join('assessment_submissions', 'assessment_submissions.courses_assessments_id', '=', 'course_assessments.id')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'assessment_submissions.evaluated_user')
            ->groupby('users.name')
            ->get();
```

I am assuming assessment_submissions table contains canvas_assignment_id column.

Comment: It didn't work because the assessment_submissions table DOESN'T contain the canvas_assignment_id column. The course_assessment table is the table that contains the canvas_assignment_id column.

Comment: which table contains canvas_assignment_id?

Comment: replace the assessment_submissions with table which contains canvas_assignment_id.

Comment: The course_assessment  table contains the canvas_assignment_id, I use "course_assessment.canvas_assignment_id", but the result it still gives me the same error.